# NavigationDrawer Listview text is white in android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I have a problem.I created listview that will be the slide in navigationDrawer. I can see the text good in Android 2.X and 5.X but in 4.2.2 the text is invisible.
This is the code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listDrawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/nliveo_white"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/nliveo_transparent"
            android:background="@color/nliveo_white"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the item code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutDados"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:id="@+id/rowIcon"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="descc" />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rowTitle"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rowIcon"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rowIcon"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textDirection="anyRtl"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try to remove this line from your ListView layout android:cacheColorHint="@color/nliveo_white"

Comment: @Govtart it's still not working

Comment: try #ff000000 instead of #000

Comment: not working, I dont know what is doing this

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your `ListView`:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listDrawer"
        android:cacheColorHint="@andorid:color/transparent" 
        ... /> <!-- change cacheColorHint to transparent -->
```

Also edit your `textColor`:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/rowTitle"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    ... /> <!-- please have 6 digits HEX code to define the color type -->
```

**Note:** A color has HEX code to define the color type, whether red, green, blue, black, etc. And HEX code has 6 digits value which combined by numbers and aplhabet or letters (starts from a to e). For example: The color from `#1eff00` HEX code is green.